# How to column-ify an output from a certain program?

Tags: text, command-line-interface

I have a program that generates and outputs a sequence of simple sample math homework tasks, like:

> 1 + 1 = ...
>   3 + 3 = ...
>   2 + 5 = ...
>   3 + 7 = ...
>   4 + 2 = ...

a sequence can be quite long, and I'd like to save space when this sequence is printed by converting it as follows:

> 1 + 1 = ...   3 + 7 = ...
>   3 + 3 = ...   4 + 2 = ...
>   2 + 5 = ...

that is, wrapping the lines into the two or more columns. I was expecting the `column` linux utility to do the job using the `-c N` option witn `N=2`, however, it still outputs the lines in one column whatever the `N` is.

How would I do the column-ifying of the sequence of lines?

Comment: Writing your own doesn't sound too complicated. What language are you using for your task?

Comment: I'm using C. But I didn't want to reinvent the wheel if the solution already exist, since the task looks pretty common.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Believe it or not, the utility you want is [pr](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_pr.htm), not columns.  If you want your file turned into 3 columns:

```
pr -3 textfile.txt
```

If you want to fill in rows first, then columns:

```
pr -l1 -t -3 textfile.txt
```

I got these sample invocations from the ever-so-useful [UNIX Power Tools](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596003307).  This is Recipe 21.16.

Answer (score 0):

The `-c` parameter to `column` is used to specify the number of "columns" your display has, counted in characters.  The `column` tool then figures out the number of "output columns" that fits in the given number of "character columns".  Passing a small number of "character columns" will almost always yield a single "output column", because more won't fit in the given number of characters.  There does not seem to be a way to pass the number of ouput columns on the command line.